# Wrong wolframalpha result, calculating Carmichael number?

Tags: wolfram-alpha, carmichael-numbers

I put to wolframalpha $3^{560}\pmod{561}$ and result should be $1$ ($561$ is Carmichael number), but result is $375.$ 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E560mod561

Why this happens? I found some online calculators which produce same mistake.

Comment: I get also $$375$$

Comment: Why should the result be $1$?

Comment: $\gcd(3,561)=3\ne1$

Comment: In number theory, a Carmichael number is a composite number n which satisfies the modular arithmetic congruence relation: b^n − 1 ≡ 1 (mod n) for all b integers. That means you can't use Fermat primality test on them because it should show you that number is prime in all tests.
561 = 3*11*17

Comment: @AdamStudenik You missed a crucial additional condition for the result $1$ , which is mentioned in the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a carmichael number $n$, the relation $b^{n-1}\equiv 1 \mod n$ holds for any numbers $b$ **relatively prime** with $n$.

For any number $b$, a carmichael number $n$ verifies
$$ b^n\equiv b \mod n$$

Which you can verify with WolframAlpha

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot give a second upvote for clarifying the correct version holding without further restrictions.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.

Comment: In this article on wiki, is this sentence good? ("A more serious flaw is that there are infinitely many Carmichael numbers. These are numbers n for which all values of a with gcd(a,n)=1 are Fermat liars.") It misdirected me, because there is missing this point.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test

Comment: There are not missing the point. The requirement about $gcd(a,n)$ is also true for the Fermat little theorem. For a given prime the results $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod p$ holds for $a$ relatively prime to $p$. Otherwise Fermat theorem state only that $a^p\equiv a \mod p$

So you can define a carmichael number to be a number "Fermat liar".